# Common action executed for multiple getters

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, getter

I'm trying to find a neat way to trigger a loading mechanism when one of several getters is first accessed. My first thoughts are about something like this:

```
public class Customer {
    private bool loaded = false;

    public int PK { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Name { get { if (!loaded) loadData(); return _name; } set { ... } }
    public string Street { get { if (!loaded) loadData(); return _street; } set { ... } }
    public string City { get { if (!loaded) loadData(); return _city; } set { ... } }
}
```

In short, in this example every `Customer` exists with its base data `PK` and `Email` until one of the other properties is accessed.

This would mean much duplicate code, increasing with the complexity of the class. Is there a way to create some kind of inheritance for these properties?

Something like this, but I don't think this is possible:

```
private void checkData() { if (!loaded) loadData(); }
public string Name:checkData { get; set; }
public string Street:checkData { get; set; }
public string City:checkData { get; set; }
```

Another way might be possible through reflection, but as I'm not experienced with it I don't know where to start here.

Any hints are deeply appreciated! ;-)

Comment: Why don't call this loadData() in constructor of class?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov loadData() is a very expensive call, and just assume I will need a complete set of the customers' emails, but only a small fraction of the 'extended' data. The real life scenario is way more complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `Lazy<T>` class to wrap the secondary properties.
This way `loadData` will only execute if any of the secondary getters is called and won't be executed more than once.

```
    public class Customer
    {

        public int PK { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Name { get { return data.Value.Name; } }
        public string Street { get { return data.Value.Street; } }
        public string City { get { return data.Value.City; } }

        public Customer()
        {
            data = new Lazy<CustomerData>(loadData);
        }


        private CustomerData loadData()
        {
            ...
        }

        private struct CustomerData
        {
            public string Name, Street, City;
        }

        private Lazy<CustomerData> data;
    }
```

Comment: Haven't heard of the `Lazy` class before, but this looks like a promising way to do this, I will give it a try and give you my feedback later. Thank you so far!

Comment: This worked for me. I can even split my extended data into groups that would likely be read in conjunction for different access scenarios. Nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is another, not so beautiful, way. You could write a wrapping generic method, which reduces the code inside your properties.

Here's an example:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return Get(m_name); }
    set { m_name = value; }
}

public static T Get<T>(T value)
{
    if (!loaded)
    {
        loadData();
    } 
    return value;
}
```

Please note, that this will decrease the performance, because your properties will always call an extra method. You can try to force the compiler to inline that method (if it does not happen already).